# Best Seforim Stores in USA and Israel?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

What seforim stores in the USA and Israel that ship, objectively, have the most extensive selection? Especially for Kabbalah, chassidus, machshava and Rav Kook?

In USA east coast region optimal. In Israel, Jerusalem and Tel Aviv area.

Comment: Not sure this is the right format for Stack Exchange. It's more of an opinion poll than a question with a specific answer.

Comment: How would you judge "best"? Most extensive selection, cheapest. Are you speaking online or offline? The USA and Israel are quite large.... aren't there particular regions more relevant to you?

Comment: If you expect to find amazing websites with broad selection in Israel, you will be disappointed. If you plan to visit bookstores in person, I like best Gitler in Bnei Brak, Pomerantz and Manny's in Jerusalem. If you know what you are looking for, Gitler is very good with shipping

Comment: This place looks interesting and with a good selection. 
https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/

Comment: What about Eichlers, ArtScroll, Greenfield Judaica etc.?

Comment: VTC as primarily opinion-based

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt We have a tag for product-recommendation. How would this be any different?

Comment: If you can get on MY, you can order from every bookstore with a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Israel - Pomeranz Bookstore in Jerusalem.

https://pomeranzbooks.com/

USA - Judaica House in Teaneck.

https://www.judaicahouse.net/

These stores have a broad selection - traditional books, as well as books on Jewish culture and history.